# How append link after images even if they have their own links

Tags: wordpress

In Wordpress I'm trying to build a function, which will append photo credits (including a link to the source) to images being inserted into the post (filter `image_send_to_editor`). The problem is, some photos may be plain, some may be wrapped in a link tag, others might have a caption and a link too.

<del>So I'm trying to build a `preg_replace` using REGEX to look for `<img>` or `<a><img></a>`, so I can append my credits. I can look for all images, but then my credits with links would be placed in the image link, which is nested links -> illegal.</del>

This is my regex so far
`(<img([^>]*)><\/a>|<img([^>]*)>)`

Which means my `<span class="photo-creds"><a href="http://source.com">Source</a></span>` should be appended after plain image tag or after the closing link tag if the image has one.

This is a testing text, where all of the images should have photo credits appended:

`<p>`Edit the Expression & Text to see matches. Roll over matches or the expression for details. PCRE & Javascript flavors of RegEx are supported. `<img src="http://www.example.com" />CREDITS HERE</p>`

The side bar includes a Cheatsheet, full Reference, and Help. You can also Save & Share with the Community, and view patterns you create or favorite in My Patterns. `<img src="http://www.example.com" />CREDITS HERE`

Explore results with the Tools below. Replace & List output custom results. Details lists capture groups. Explain describes your expression in plain English. `<a href="http://image.png"><img src="http://www.example.com" /></a>CREDITS HERE`

Comment: Might be a case of [Tony the pony he comes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Ok, if using regex to append my photo credits in WP is foolish, then how can this be done without crippling my site (performance-wise)?